# Error adding dependencies to build.gradle Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I orginally had this:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I tried to add a dependency for google play service I added this code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
```

and I am now getting this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.

The error is with the appcompat dependency and the firebase dependency even though they worked just fine before I added the google play services dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your Firebase dependency to match the `play-services` version.

Change your Firebase dependency to:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0
```

And your support dependencies to:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Comment: this solved the error for the firebase but i still have the error on the appcompat dependency

Comment: im now getting this error --
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex